# Angular convert date to Long Date through pipe in the template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

For example I have a date input like 2022-04-02T00:00:00 when I use
`{{data?.dateStarted | date:'MM/dd/YYYY'}}` the output would be  04/02/2022. But how do we convert to Long Date like April 2, 2022.

Any idea guys ? would really appreciate it , thanks. regards.

Comment: From the docs: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe. `'longDate'` or `'MMMM d, y'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Momentjs, it makes date conversion so much easier with clean code.
Check this for all possible formats:  https://momentjs.com/

```
npm install --save moment
import * as moment from 'moment';

const formattedDate = moment(this.existingDate).format('MMM Do YY');
```

Comment: why on earth you import moment only for formatting a date instead using angular pipe date???????